# ASP.net - Get ID from URL

Tags: asp.net, url, query-string

I have a datalist and I'm sending the user ID of the user through the URL to another page:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="LastNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("LastName") %>' NavigateUrl='<%# FormatUrl( (int) Eval("FriendsAccountID")) %>' />
```

and the function:

```
protected string FormatUrl(int FriendsAccountID)
{
    return "WebForm3.aspx?" + FriendsAccountID;
}
```

---

This works but I'm kind of a noobie and I'm not sure how get the ID once I'm on the next page. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
protected string FormatUrl(int FriendsAccountID) { return "WebForm3.aspx?UserID=" + FriendsAccountID; }
```

Then you can access the UserID like this:

```
Request.QueryString["UserID"];
```

Here is a link to [QueryString on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring.aspx).

Comment: Can that go straight into the page load WebForm3?

Comment: Yes. Every Webform has access to the Request object.

Answer (score 0):

You should set ID to that url variable, like this:

```
protected string FormatUrl(int FriendsAccountID)
{
  return "WebForm3.aspx?FriendID=" + FriendsAccountID.ToString();
}
```

And on other page (WebForm3.aspx in your case) user Request.Params or QueryString to get that value :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int friendID = -1;

    if (Request.Params["FrientID"] != null && int.TryParse(Request.Params["FrientID"], out friendID)
    {
      // you got a valid friend id in friendID variable
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use **sessions** and pass your `ID` using `query string`.Then from otherpage you can easily access that ID